# React Redux state array changes are not re-rendering a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a project that uses React + Redux + Thunk and I am rather new to the stack. I have a scenario where I am fetching an array from an API call in my action/reducer, but it is not re-rendering in a component/container that is hooked up to the Store. The component does render the first time when I fire up the app, but at that point the array is `undefined` when logged to console.

I am trying to display the array's length, so this is always resulting in `0`. With ReduxDevTools I see that the state of `network_identities` does populate correctly and is longer zero... Where am I going wrong?

*Here is my sample action*

```
///////////// Sample action ///////////// 
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'sample@url.com';
const authorization = 'sample_auth';

export function fetchConnections() {

    const params = {
            headers: {
            authorization,
        },
    };

    return (dispatch) => {
        // call returns an array of items
        axios.get(`${url}/connection`, params)
        .then((connections) => {

            let shake_profiles = [];
            let connected_profiles = [];
            let entity_res;

            // map through items to fetch the items data, and split into seperate arrays depending on 'status'
            connections.data.forEach((value) => {
                switch (value.status) {
                case 'APPROVED': case 'UNAPPROVED':
                    {
                    axios.get(`${url}/entity/${value.entity_id_other}`, params)
                    .then((entity_data) => {
                        entity_res = entity_data.data;
                        // add status
                        entity_res.status = value.status;
                        // append to connected_profiles
                        connected_profiles.push(entity_res);
                    });
                    break;
                    }
                case 'CONNECTED':
                    {
                    axios.get(`${url}/entity/${value.entity_id_other}`, params)
                    .then((entity_data) => {
                        entity_res = entity_data.data;
                        entity_res.status = value.status;
                        shake_profiles.push(entity_res);
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log('err fetching entity info: ', err));
                    break;
                    }
                // if neither case do nothing
                default: break;
                }
            });

            dispatch({
                type: 'FETCH_CONNECTIONS',
                payload: { shake_profiles, connected_profiles },
            });
        });
    };
}
```

*Sample Reducer*

```
///////////// Sample reducer ///////////// 
const initialState = {
    fetched: false,
    error: null,
    connections: [],
    sortType: 'first_name',
    filterType: 'ALL',
    shake_identities: [],
    network_identities: [],
};

const connectionsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_CONNECTIONS':
        console.log('[connections REDUCER] shake_profiles: ', action.payload.shake_profiles);
        console.log('[connections REDUCER] connected_profiles: ', action.payload.connected_profiles);
        return { ...state,
        fetched: true,
        shake_identities: action.payload.shake_profiles,
        network_identities: action.payload.connected_profiles,
        };
    default:
        return state;
    }
};

export default connectionsReducer;
```

*Sample Store*

```
///////////// Sample Store /////////////
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import reducers from './reducers';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk);
// Redux Dev Tools
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(middleware));

export default store;
```

*Sample Component - see if the API is done fetching the array, then display the length of the array*

```
///////////// Sample Component /////////////
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import * as ConnectionActions from 'actions/connections';

import styles from './styles.scss';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
    network_identities: state.connections.network_identities,
    loadedConnections: state.connections.fetched,
};
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, ConnectionActions), dispatch),
};
}

class Counter extends Component {
componentWillMount() {
    const { network_identities, actions } = this.props;
    if (!network_identities.length) {
    console.log('||| fetching Connections');
    actions.fetchConnections();
    }
}

render() {
    let { network_identities, loadedConnections} = this.props;

    console.log('[Counter] network_identities[0]: ', network_identities[0]);
    console.log('[Counter] network_identities: ', network_identities);
    console.log('[Counter] loadingConnections: ', loadingConnections);

    return (
    <div>
        <Link to="/network">
        <div>
            <span>Connections</span>
            { !loadedConnections ? (
            <span><i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" /></span>
            ) : (
            <span>{network_identities.length}</span>
            ) }
        </div>
        </Link>
    </div>
    );
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CSSModules(Counter, styles));
```

I suspect I am either mutating the state in my reducer, or I am misusing Thunk.

Comment: Quick question, what version of react are you using?  There were some changes as of React 16 that may change the answer to this.  Prior to 16 you could make use of the componentWillReceiveProps() life cycle function and in fact even post React 16 I think you would still use this to update state synchronously.  Pass something to componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) and console.log nextProps and you should see your changes which you can then use to update the component as needed.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, I'd recommend to separate api client logic from actions. Things like setting custom headers and authorization shouldn't be handled in an action creator module.

Comment: @Ron React is version 15.6.2. Will give that strategy a go, thanks!

Comment: That `connections.data.forEach` is sketchy, as it won't wait until the fetches have completed. The fetches will mutate the state afterwards, but won't trigger a rerender because dispatch has already fired. Might be better to map the `connections` to promises and wait for the results with `.all()`.

Comment: @AdB I double checked and this should be fine even in 16.  16.3 is where the change occurs where this is now considered a legacy lifecycle method.  This article explains it better than I could.

https://medium.com/@baphemot/whats-new-in-react-16-3-d2c9b7b6193b

Also I added a more in-depth example as an answer below.

Comment: Don't think this has anything to do with lifecycles. Do the `[connections REDUCER]` console logs in `connectionsReducer` print two empty arrays?

Comment: @Oblosys `[connections REDUCER]` initially logs `[]`. When i inspect it and the value is evaluated then it becomes the proper array populated with data... Also I am trying your Promise.all() approach, just trying to figure out how to implement it at the moment :)

Comment: I think I know what's going on. I can put an idea for a solution in an answer.

Comment: @Oblosys I am all ears! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the code is that `connections.data.forEach((value) => {..})` will send out a bunch of fetches, and then immediately return without waiting for the result arrays to be populated. A `'FETCH_CONNECTIONS'` action is dispatched with empty arrays, and all connected components will rerender with the empty results.

What makes it tricky though is that the array objects that you put in the store will get pushed to once the fetches finish, so when you inspect the store it will seem populated correctly.

Not using any mutations will prevent the accidental population of the store, but won't solve the fact that dispatch is fired before the results are in. To do that, you could either create actions to add single results and dispatch those in the `axios.get().then` parts, or you could create a list of promises and wait for all of them to resolve with `Promise.all()`.

Here's what the latter solution could look like.

```
axios.get(`${url}/connection`, params)
.then((connections) => {

  const connectionPromises = connections.data.map((value) => {
    switch (value.status) {
      case 'APPROVED': case 'UNAPPROVED':
        return axios.get(`${url}/entity/${value.entity_id_other}`, params)
        .then((entity_data) => {
          return {connected_profile: {...entity_data.data, status: value.status}};
        });
      case 'CONNECTED':
        return axios.get(`${url}/entity/${value.entity_id_other}`, params)
        .then((entity_data) => {
            return {shake_profile: {...entity_data.data, status: value.status}};
        })
      // if neither case do nothing
      default:
        return {};
    }
  });

  Promise.all(connectionPromises)
  .then((connections) => {
    const connected_profiles =
      connections.filter((c) => c.connected_profile).map((r) => r.connected_profile);
    const shake_profiles =
      connections.filter((c) => c.shake_profile).map((r) => r.shake_profile);

    dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_CONNECTIONS',
      payload: { shake_profiles, connected_profiles },
    });
  }).catch(err => console.log('err fetching entity info: ', err));

});
```

You'll probably want to use some more appropriate names though, and if you use lodash, you can make it a bit prettier.

Comment: That was it! thanks so much! Could you explain the double return? this part confuses me: `return axios.get('content', params)
        .then((entity_data) => {
          return {connected_profile: {...entity_data.data, status: value.status}};
        });`

Comment: The outer return is to return the promise to the `map` callback, so it ends up in the array. The inner return is to return the value the promise will resolve to. You can get rid of the inner return by rewriting `(arg) => {return {...}}` to `(arg) => ({...})` if you like.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are making an async operation within a componentWillMount. When this lifecycle method is called,it does not block the render method from being called. That is, it does not wait until there is a response from its operations. So, rather move this async action to componentDidMount.